# How to determine if a client selected "ok" in a tkinter messagebox?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkmessagebox

For a program I'm creating which edits MIDI files, I imported the `tkinter.messagebox` module. The messagebox function I'm using is `askokcancel`. I want all the parent and child windows to close when <kbd>ok</kbd> is selected. How do I accomplish this?

I've already tried going on other sites to see how, but I didn't find any answers.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox

class Window(Frame):

        def init_window(self):

        menu = Menu(self.master)

        self.master.config(menu=menu)

        file = Menu(menu)

        file.add_command(label="Exit", command=self.client_exit)

        menu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=file)

    def exit(self):

        exit()

    def client_exit(self):

        messagebox.askokcancel('Exit?', 'Are you sure you want to exit?', default='ok') 

#Here, I want the "exit" function to be the function.

        if self.reading:

            self.top.quit()

app = Window(tk)
```

This is just a sample of my code I shared. If there is a possible error with the other code, I'll share it.

Answer (score 2):

```
def client_exit(self):
    MsgBox = messagebox.showinfo('Exit?', 'Are you sure you want to exit?',icon = 'warning')
    if MsgBox == 'ok':
        #Some code
```

[image]

or:

```
def client_exit(self):
    MsgBox = messagebox.askquestion ('Exit?', 'Are you sure you want to exit?',icon = 'warning')
    if MsgBox == 'yes':
        # Your code
    else:
        # Your code
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks... I appreciate it.